# Class method returns undefined bound/unbound JavaScript

Tags: javascript, class, methods, return, undefined

Thank you in advance for any help.

Why does the return statement from return this.visited inside the if(this.queue.length === 0) code block return undefined? Whereas both console.logs before the return statement return the correct values.

What I tried: I read through a few related post here and then tried binding this to the this.traverse method. I reviewed the syntax, logic, checked for typos several times.

```
const Tree = require('../Tree/treeExport')
const Queue = require('../Stack_Queue/queueExport')

class BFS extends Tree {

    constructor(queue,queue1) {
        super()

        this.visited = queue
        this.queue = queue1

        this.traverse = this.traverse.bind(this)
    }

    traverse() {

        let current;

        if(this.visited.length < 1) {     
            this.queue.enqueue(this.root)
        }

       if(this.queue.length > 0) {
        current = this.queue.dequeue()
       }

        if(current.left) {
            this.queue.enqueue(current.left)
        }  
        if(current.right) {
            this.queue.enqueue(current.right)
        }

        if(current) {
            this.visited.enqueue(current.value)
        }

        if(this.queue.length === 0) {
            console.log(this.visited, '\n \n')
            console.log(this.mapToArray(this.visited), '\n \n')

            return this.visited;


        } else {
            this.traverse()
        }
    }
    mapToArray(queue) {
        const array = []
        let temp;
        while(queue.length > 0) {
            temp = queue.dequeue()
            array.push(temp)
        }

        temp = null;
        return array;

    }

}
 let queue = new Queue
 let visited = new Queue
 const bfs = new BFS(visited,queue)

bfs.insert(5)
bfs.insert(3)
bfs.insert(7)
bfs.insert(2)
bfs.insert(4)
bfs.insert(6)
bfs.insert(9)

console.log(bfs.traverse())
```

result from console:

```
Queue {
  first: Node { value: 5, next: Node { value: 3, next: [Node] } },        
  last: Node { value: 9, next: null },
  length: 7
}


[
  5, 3, 7, 2,
  4, 6, 9
]


undefined
```

Comment: The `traverse` method doesn't return anything. EDIT: to clarify - not in all cases. So if you're not in the only `if` that has a `return`, there would be no return value.

Comment: I got it to work, thanks again. I couldn't see I wasn't returning anything for a very long time.